# Multiboot disabled by default, Ubuntu Windows dual boot, Acer Aspire TC-780

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, acer, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 20 along with Windows 10, however, the only boot option I can see is only Windows and the others are disabled and hidden, and whenever I try to modify the other boot options to normal/enabled it always set them automatically to disabled the available boot options:

[image: Screenshot]

I need to find a solution to set both of them to enabled and be able to boot into any of them.

When I try to edit the boot order I can't even see ubuntu on the list because it's set to hidden (only the windows bootmanager is enabled)

The partition where I installed Ubuntu is visible in the partition manager but it's hidden in the file explorer and not able to access it.

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 20 what did you install and how?

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ start with this site, you seem to not be clear on what you are doing.

Comment: You seem to be encountering correct and expected behavior *when using Windows Boot Manager*. That's why the Ubuntu installer adds a different bootloader that is compatible with both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Acer's used to require "trust" setting to activate the Ubuntu entry. Most also needed UEFI update.  Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: I installed Ubuntu and also Debian, both of them are not on the boot menu. only windows, my system uses UEFI, I followed all the steps for dual boot in UEFI, but nothing seems to be working, and only one system from what I have installed is bootable.

Comment: Your comments seems to imply you simply ignored the previous comment and its link.

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying. For David's reply, I have already followed all the steps mentioned in your link, except the /home directory that I didn't create during installation, but only the root / . For user535733 reply, I have installed Ubuntu with 2 ways, the first was to select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows bootmanager" and the second "something else" and to create a partition, one EXT4 with mount point "/", and the other is swap partition, I have also, in one of my attempts, selected install the bootloader on Windows bootmanager, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: For Oldfred reply, I have checked your links, the first is for setting up Ubuntu, the second , I can see different options on my PC, please refer to the link to see the images of what I see, I can't find the option "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing", I tried setting up a supervisor password, and it also shows the same thing. https://imgur.com/a/wvZfgIj

Comment: @ChangAuto, thank you for your reply, I didn't ignore anything, it was a clarification for the first comment, and I didn't have time yesterday to go through the links so I did it today and replied, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the solution for the dual boot problem

After installing Ubuntu and the boot menu doesn't appear, we access the Ubuntu from the Usb we used to install and select Try Ubuntu.

1. Install the tool Boot-Repair using these commands

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install -y boot-repair

2. - boot-repair

- select repair boot loader and it will solve everything and install the GRUB bootloader